# Reload/Refresh View Controller on Significant Location Change (from App Delegate)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to have my view refreshed using significant location changed. The location manager is in my app delegate, and I am trying to use the NSNotificationCenter to tell the view controller to refresh if the user changes locations. I am not sure how to refresh to refresh the view. I currently  have it set up like below. I made a "View Controller (refresh the view)" block where I think the code for the refresh would take place. Anyone know how to make this work? Thank you!

**App Delegate (listen for significant location changes):**

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation  
*)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshView" object:nil];

}
```

**View Controller (Listen to NSNotificationCenter):**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshView:) 
name:@"refreshView" object:nil];

}
```

**View Controller (refresh the view):**

```
-(void)refreshView:(NSNotification *) notification {

//CODE TO REFRESH THE VIEW HERE

}
```

Comment: UIViewController* root = _window.rootViewController;
   UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)root;
   YourViewController * mycontroller = (YourViewController *)[[navController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
   [mycontroller reloadInputViews];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-(void)refreshView:(NSNotification *) notification {

[self viewDidLoad];
[self viewWillAppear]; // If viewWillAppear also contains code

}
```

Comment: Thanks Sudesh. So I can literally call [self viewDidLoad] again?

Comment: Yes you can :) but careful about if any variable is created inside viewDidLoad then it will creates another instance and can increase memory.

Comment: So before creation of any variable release old one if you not using ARC.

Comment: Got it - using ARC so should be OK yes?

Comment: -1 This needs to be fixed. Move the stuff in viewDidLoad outside and call that method. Calling viewDidLoad should happen only when... The view actually loads

Comment: This answer needs to be fixed. It is not advised to call ViewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear by yourself.

In the ViewDidLoad include a loadData() function to prepare the data. This is executed in the initial run. When you want to reload, call loadData() again to get the data from model. In a tableView call reloadData() or in a regular view setNeedsDisplay().

Comment: Never call viewDidLoad() directly. This is explicitly only ever to be called once during the lifecylcle of the App. Instead call loadViewIfNeeded()

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621360-viewifloaded